# awk определить конец строки

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Если строка в файле оканчивается на восклицательный или вопросительный знак,
то за этой строкой нужно добавить пустую строку. Как найти конец строки в awk?
 С awk не приходилось иметь дело.
 Мои попытки, но такой вариант не срабатывает:

```
$awk '/[!?]$/{ print $0"\n"}' file
```

Если файл записан так: 
*Why do they make so many mistakes?

A:So you’re Harry’s cousin?

B: Yes. That’s right.*

То хотелось бы получить такое:
*Why do they make so many mistakes?


A:So you’re Harry’s cousin?


B: Yes. That’s right.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sed* подойдёт?

```sh
$ sed -e 's/[!?]$/\0\n/' ./file.txt
```

Так-то через *awk* тоже можно, но сложнее:

```sh
$ awk '/[!?]$/ { print $0 "\n"; next; } { print; }' ./file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $awk '/[!?]$/{ print $0"\n"}' file
> ```

в таком варианте строки, не удовлетворяющие условию `[!?]$`, вообще не будут напечатаны.

например, можно добавить вызов `print` **вне** условной констркции `/.../{...}`, а внутри этой конструкции не вызывать `print`, а изменять содержимое переменной `$0`:

```
$awk '/[!?]$/{ $0 = $0"\n" }; { print }' file
```